# Install SSL certificate from an untrusted website into the Certificates snap-in using IE

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer, ssl, certificate

How can I install a certificate from an untrusted website into the Certificates snap-in (certmgr.msc) of Windows?

[image]

I know how to do this with Firefox by exporting to a file and then importing it, but I'm looking to do this in IE or with any other way that's built-in to Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I knew this used to be easy. It turns out the trick is to **run IE as an Administrator**:

[image]

Then browse to the website and click on the certificate details:

[image]

Then finally you can *Install Certificate*:

[image]

If you then want to export it to a file, it's a simple matter of exporting it from the Certificates (certmgr.msc) snap-in.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend reading [this KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/179380), especially the Import and Export sections. To summarize:

1. Press `WinKey+R` and at the `Run` window
2. Type in `control inetcpl.cpl,,3` (there are two commas and the number three at the end, yes)
3. Click on `Certificates` button
4. Click on the `Trusted Root Certification Authorities` (or the appropriate tab for your certificate) and locate the certificate you want to export.
5. Click on the `Export...` button then `Next`
6. Select the format you want to save the certificate under and click `Next`
7. Type in a name. By default, exported certificate will be saved under your current profile's Documents folder. Click `Next`
8. Click `Finish` If everything went well, you should see a `The export was successful` pop-up.

Hope that helps.

Comment: The problem I had wasn't exporting it from the Certificates store. It was getting a cert from a website into the Ceritificates store in the first place.

Comment: Your question didn't say that. It asked: `After browsing to an SSL-enabled website in IE, how can I export that SSL certificate to a file so that it can be later imported into the Certificates (certmgr.msc) snap-in?` May want to edit and reword it. Just a suggestion.

Comment: @MichaelKropat - IE uses the Microsoft Store.   So these instructions are actually correct as per how the question is currently worded.

Comment: @Ramhound how would you word the question? I've attempted to follow this answer, but the certificate I want doesn't show up on the `Trusted Root Certification Authorities` tab (or any other tab that I can see).

Comment: @MichaelKropat: How about this? `How can I save a certificate from an untrusted website so that I can add it later to the Certificates snap-in of Windows?` or something along those lines?

Comment: Cool, seems clearer. Updated.