# How to resolve "Content was blocked" issue in IE11 in a part of the page?

Tags: windows-8, ssl-certificate, internet-explorer-11

I am using IE11 on windows 8 and usually get this page which is unable to load further:

[image]
<sub>(the address was cut from the image because it's a private site)</sub>

How can I display this type of content - e.g. add an exception or doing any other resolution?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Install SSL certificate from an untrusted website into the Certificates snap-in using IE](http://superuser.com/questions/713810/install-ssl-certificate-from-an-untrusted-website-into-the-certificates-snap-in)

Comment: The suggested duplicate is for Windows 7. It should be something similar in 8.

Comment: i already installed SSL but yet not working.

Comment: Then the first step would be to see the site's certificate and find out what is "invalid" about it from IE's standpoint.

Comment: Okay, I see that the root certificate is not trusted. The suggested duplicate is lacking information about installing that. I'll show how to install it after I set up a VM with an English Windows version.

Comment: While you're waiting, you should find a way to open certificate properties window in IE11 (if you haven't already). I don't have it so I cannot help you here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47953/discussion-between-aishwarya-taneja-and-ivan-pozdeev).

Comment: How you trust the root is the same as how you trust any certificate you add it to the certificate store

Comment: @Ramhound Well, first, you need to select it in the chain (that's non-trivial :) ). Then, it never worked for me unless I select a certificate store manually.

Comment: The problem depicted turned out to be different from the root certificate issue, so this is not a duplicate.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev how you save off a root certificate and drop and drag it into the store is exactly how you do it for the websites certificate (just saying)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A TeamViewer support session revealed that the specific error depicted in the question is different from the root certificate problem outlined in [the other answer](https://superuser.com/questions/1142122/how-to-resolve-content-was-blocked-issue-in-ie11-and-make-it-display-it/1142154#1142154) (though that was an issue, too).

The part of the page that doesn't load is a [frame](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Framing_%28World_Wide_Web%29). The root page was accessing it as `https://172.16.xx.xx/<etc>` (a server on the OP's corporate network apparently) while the certificate at that server is issued for some DNS name. **That server name mismatch is the source of the error.**

Technically, this is a problem with the business app installation and should be resolved by the local operations team.

Yet, we found a way around that *without* compromising IE's security.

It turns out, **[adding the site to Trusted Sites](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie9-windows_7/how-do-i-add-a-site-to-my-trusted-sites-list/98cc77c8-b364-e011-8dfc-68b599b31bf5) stops IE from complaining about certificate errors for its frames.**

(Do not forget to restart the browser after the change.)

Answer (score 1):

I don't have Windows 8 or IE 11, so I can only show the corresponding interface in IE 8.

Opening the certificate properties as outlined in [Install SSL certificate from an untrusted website into the Certificates snap-in using IE](https://superuser.com/questions/713810/install-ssl-certificate-from-an-untrusted-website-into-the-certificates-snap-in/713821#713821), then going to the "Certification Path" tab shows the following:

[image: certificate properties]

As you can see, the root certificate is not trusted by IE - that's the cause of the error. We need to install it into the local trusted root certificate store.

Select the root certificate, then press "View Certificate" for it and "Install certificate..." in the properties window that opens. In the opening wizard, choose to select the store manually and use the "Trusted Root Certification Authorities" one:

[image: installing root certificate]

After clicking "OK", "Yes" and similar everywhere, restart the browser.

Now we can see the certificate is trusted:

[image: certificate ok]

Answer (score -1):

**Security risk**

Go to tools>internet options>advanced and uncheck the box that tells IE to check for a certificate.

Comment: You've got to the kidding to suggest this a the normal course of action.